# how to do a clean up in useeffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**How to clean up the function retrieve in cleanup**

i am not able to clean up pls help

```
const retrieve = async()=>{
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('users');
    
      if (value !== null) {
        //  console.log("data inside async storagein deregister screen",value);
        var replace_brackets = value.replace("["," ").replace("]","")
        setList(JSON.parse(value))
        }
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        retrieve()
        return function cleanup(){
          retrieve()
        }

      })
```

Comment: What is there to clean up? I don't see any added listeners or subscriptions or timer intervals that need to be removed, unsubscribed from, or cleared.

Comment: it says cleanup if i dont add a clean up in useffect

Comment: actually this is happening on a different screen other than the on where i am writing to async storage

Comment: Are you referring to the async storage access and trying to later update state? What are you calling that code from? Are you trying to put a `useEffect` hook in the `retrieve` function?

Comment: i want just read my async storage as soon as the app opens up so i am using a useeffect is it the right way to do .?

Comment: Yes, you use a mounting `useEffect`, i.e. with empty dependency array (`[]`) to fetch and set state when the component mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Inside you app/any other component add:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        retrieve();
},[])
```

The above code basically runs like componentDidMount.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably how you have defined your `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
   retrieve()
   return function cleanup(){
      retrieve()
   }

})
```

The above useEffect that you have written will execute on every render. On load it will call retrieve and inside retrieve you are setting state so it may re-trigger this effect in an infinite loop.

By simply adding the dependencies to useEffect or keeping it empty if you want it to run only on page load you may not require a clean up function here.

try this.

```
useEffect(() => {

  retrieve();

}, []) //Note empty brackets here for executing only on mount
```